# C user input and Linked List

Tags: c, linked-list, stdin, fgets

I am trying to intake a string from user input and then compare that to my linked list that i have created previously in the code and find the location as to where the string should be inserted. And stop looping when user enters nothing and hits enter.

I am able to intake the string and find the location to insert, but what I want to do is to loop until the user enters a blank input. This is causing my code to break somewhere and I am not quite sure why. I have inserted break points in my code to debug it, but I believe I am having issue with fgets. Any help would be amazing.

When I say that the code "breaks", what the output looks like is something like this:

```
BREAK1: AAAA

BREAK2
BREAK4
               AAAA
   0
BREAK5
```

The string and the position are correct, but it is printing on multiple lines, and then after this, it continues to loop without resetting. Below is my code::

```
// NO FILE, SO INTAKE STRINGS
///////////////////////////////////////////////////
///////////////////////////////////////////////////
else{
    fgets(buff,BUFF_SIZE,stdin);
    buff[strlen(buff)] = '\0';

    while (buff[0] != '\0'){
        printf("BREAK1: %s\n", buff);
        // set curr = root node
        curr = root;
        printf("BREAK2\n");
        while (curr->next){
            if (strcmp(buff, curr->stringDat) == 1){
                insertPnt++;
                curr = curr->next;
                printf("BREAK3\n");
            }
            else{
                printf("BREAK4\n");
                insert(buff, insertPnt, root);
                printf("%20s   %d\n", buff, insertPnt);
                break;
            }
        }

        // clear buffer
        for (i = 0; i < BUFF_SIZE; i++) {
            buff[i] = 0;
        }
        printf("BREAK5\n");
        // user input
        fgets(buff, BUFF_SIZE, stdin);
        buff[strlen(buff)] = '\0';
        printf("BREAK6\n");
    }
}
```

**** UPDATED CODE (STILL NOT STOPPING ON BLANK ENTRY) ****

```
else{
        while (fgets(buff, BUFF_SIZE, stdin) != NULL){
            buff[strlen(buff) - 1] = '\0';
            insertPnt = 1;

            printf("BREAK1: %s\n", buff);
            // set curr = root node
            curr = root;
            printf("BREAK2\n");
            while (curr->next){
                if (strcmp(buff, curr->stringDat) > 0){
                    insertPnt++;
                    curr = curr->next;
                }
                else{
                    insert(buff, insertPnt, root);
                    printf("%-20s   %d\n", buff, insertPnt);
                    // PRINT LINKED LIST
                    print(root);
                    break;
                }
            }

            // clear buffer
            for (i = 0; i < BUFF_SIZE; i++) {
                buff[i] = 0;
            }
            printf("BREAK5\n");

        }
    }
```

Comment: Possibly related to your question... After the `fgets` calls `buff[strlen(buff)]` is already equal to the string terminator. If you want to remove the ***possible*** trailing newline you should be using `buff[strlen(buff) - 1] = '\0'`.

Comment: By the way, the correct way to see if `fgets` succeeded or not is to check if it returned `NULL`. So a loop like `while (fgets(...) != NULL)` is usually used.

Comment: What, in the documentation for [`strcmp()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcmp), leads you to believe that function it will *predictably* return `1`, specifically in the test of `if (strcmp(buff, curr->stringDat) == 1)` ?

Comment: @WhozCraig, good point, I changed my code to be > 0...thank you for pointing this out.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude that did indeed help, my only issue now is entering a blank string is not stopping the loop still...see above for updated code

Comment: @Dpry12 that's because your updated code has absolutely nothing besides a failure of `fgets` to break the outer `while` loop. `fgets` doesn't fail on a line containing only a `'\n'`. [Why not just do something like this?](http://ideone.com/sNTKL4)

Answer (score 2):

> The string and the position are correct, but it is printing on
>   multiple lines

Because you are not stripping the trailing new-line lefted by `fgets`:

```
fgets(buff,BUFF_SIZE,stdin);
buff[strlen(buff)] = '\0'; /* This is a NO-OP */
```

Change to

```
char *ptr;
fgets(buff,BUFF_SIZE,stdin);
if (ptr = strchr(buff, '\n')) {
    *ptr = '\0';
}
```