# C inserting into linked list, issue with first and last node

Tags: c, linked-list, insert

Below you will find my code, it is inserting properly anywhere in between the first and last nodes, but when I try to insert before the first node, or after the last, it is failing. I currently cannot figure it out, and was wondering if anybody could help. Thank you!

When I say it is not working, it does not fail out, it just will not insert at the first node or after the final node. There is no error message being thrown. I am thinking it may be an issue in the main body, vs the insert function

MAIN BODY (PORTION):

```
else{
        while (fgets(buff, BUFF_SIZE, stdin) != NULL){

            if (strlen(buff) == 1)
                break;

            buff[strlen(buff) - 1] = '\0';
            insertPnt = 1;

            // set curr = root node
            curr = root;
            while (curr){
                if (strcmp(buff, curr->stringDat) > 0){
                    insertPnt++;
                    curr = curr->next;
                }
                else{
                    insert(buff, insertPnt, root);
                    printf("STRING: %-20s  POSITION: %d\n", buff, insertPnt);

                    break;
                }
            }
            // clear buffer
            for (i = 0; i < BUFF_SIZE; i++) {
                buff[i] = 0;
            }
        }
    }
```

INSERT FUNCTION:

```
void insert(char* stringArg, int position, NODE* rootNodeArg){
    int i, strDatLen;

    /* Declaring node */
    NODE* temp = (NODE*)malloc(sizeof(NODE));

    strDatLen = strlen(stringArg);
    temp->stringDat = malloc(sizeof(char)*strDatLen);

    strcpy(temp->stringDat,stringArg);
    temp->next = NULL;



    /* if node insertion at first point */
    if (position == 1)
    {
        temp->next = rootNodeArg;
        rootNodeArg = temp;
        return;
    }

    /* Adding & Adjusting node links*/
    NODE* traverse = rootNodeArg;
    for (i = 0; i<position - 2; i++)
    {
        traverse = traverse->next;
    }
    temp->next = traverse->next;
    traverse->next = temp;

}
```

Comment: What's the problem? Could you elaborate a bit? BTW you must check `malloc` return values `!= NULL`

Comment: Please specifiy what "failing" means. Add an error message please. Or is the code simply not working the way it should?

Comment: added some more details above @SgtTrace

Comment: I can already tell you [from your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40604081/c-user-input-and-linked-list) one of your problems is passing the root node pointer *by value*; not by address. This: `rootNodeArg = temp;` means *nothing* to the caller of this function (ie. `main()`). Their pointer remains unchanged.

Comment: @WhozCraig thanks for the comment, in the function, I am passing the pointer to the root...isn't that passing by ref? Or am I missing something?

Comment: That only passes the address of the data pointed to by `root` (or null on an empty list). That's not what you want to change. You want to change the root pointer itself (potentially). And like all things in C (arrays notwithstanding), if you want to change something via function call, you need to declare the formal parameter to be a pointer to type, and dereference on assignment. That your pointed-to type is already a pointer type makes no difference. That just means your formal parameter should  be a pointer-to-pointer.

Comment: @WhozCraig, ok...so I have changed it to be `void insert(char* stringArg, int position, NODE** rootNodeArg)`   and when calling it `insert(buff, insertPnt, &root);` now I am getting an "assignment from incompatible pointer type" error from in the function...working on that now

Comment: @WhozCraig , I also have changed the code to be `temp->next = *rootNodeArg;
  *rootNodeArg = temp;`, but that did not fix the issue, still working on it though

Comment: @Dpry12 so long as you actually know what you're doing. This isn't something you guess at. If you do, you may actually stumble on the correct sequence of commands, but never understand *why* they're correct. I have to ask. Why scan the list just to count the hops to the insertion point, then scan it *again* to do the insertion. Why not just insert it the first time, returning the insertion point counter as the otherwise-unused result of `insert` ? Eg: [like this](http://ideone.com/7jTwzr).

Comment: @WhozCraig, your code helped a ton, I see what I was doing wrong now. I was missing the &(*root) piece, and streamlining it to scan only once made it much simpler as well. Thank you so much for your help

Answer (score 1):

You have a big problem with size of string

```
temp->stringDat = malloc(sizeof(char)*strDatLen);
```

must be

```
temp->stringDat = malloc( strDatLen+1);
```

To create space for null terminator.

As you can see on [the man](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strlen.3.html) strlen return the number of chars into c-string noy counting the byte for the null terminator.

Comment: I made the change to all my malloc's...thank you for the help